# Cannot install pandas datareader package. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, api, prediction

I am trying to build a prediction model and needs to get data from stock API. Found that pandas datareader is the way to go. But when I try to install it using

```
conda install -c delichon pandas_datareader
```

[image] the following error occurs. I have python version 3.8

I tried installing pandas-datareader using 'conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader' which was successful but couldn't use it in code.

I am trying to run

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
```

for which I get the error No module named '`pandas_datareader`'

Answer (score 1):

There may be an issue about your conda environment. You should check your Python version of conda environment.

```
conda env list
* activate your conda environment
conda activate example-env
python --version
```

Or

Please check the installed Python versions of your Conda

```
conda list python -f
```

Or you can directly create a new conda environment with Python 3

```
conda create --name env-name python=3.8
```

Comment: Turns out 'conda list python -f' gives version as 2.7

Comment: Your conda works with only Python 2. You should update your conda or reinstall the new version. Then create a new environment with Python 3.